# Trying to output current row of a table with columns that have the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a table that has several columns. I only included one row in the code below. The left columns are a drop down select lists. What I need to happen is when I select an option of the dropdown, It should trigger an event (the one I have in the JS). 
It does trigger however, but it is not returning the row of the selector that was pressed. These need to have the same name and ID because my post reads these as arrays.

Later I am wanting to add an ajax call to what I have on the trigger so that I can get information for other columns of the same row in a get request. To do this, I need to get the value of the item selected and the row of the item selected.

How do I do that?

```
 <tbody>
            <tr id="0">
                <td>
                <select class="form-control taskDropdown" id="TaskID" name="TaskID"><option value="">-Select-</option>
                <option value="1">A00</option>
                </select></td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>11</td>
            </tr>
<tr id="1">
            <td>
            <select class="form-control taskDropdown" id="TaskID" name="TaskID"><option value="">-Select-</option>
            <option value="1">A00</option>
            </select></td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Here is the trigger and getter for the closest ancestor row, but it returns null:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.taskDropdown').change(function (e) {
            console.log("dropdown selected");
            var currentRow = $(e).closest('tr');
            alert(currentRow.id);
        });
});
```

Comment: is `console.log("dropdown selected");` prints ?

Comment: yes. it does trigger that a dropdown does get selected. However, I don't know how to get the value of it from the trigger, or tell what row it was.

Comment: You're trying to print an `id` of the <tr> without set id

Comment: Ultimately, I am wanting to be able to select the drop down, then do an ajax call and then append the row with the result of the drop down that was selected. If I can get the row and the value of the selector, I already know how to do the rest.

Comment: Can you post a few rows and name them as you have explained?

Comment: $(this).closest("tr")

Comment: I updated the code, they are all the same until modified. @Sachin does this not mean e? in this context?

Comment: e is for event not for event target. $(this) works $(e) does not.

Comment: alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));